# Custom shopping cart and I have the customers details - I just need to take the payment

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I have been building an e-commerce web application, I have got my shopping basket and customers details now I need to send the basket items over to pay pal for processing, in the paste I have used instant notification but this way years and years a go.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for setting up paypal using c# to send  my shopping basket over to pay pal, what are the latest techniques?

Pay pal. Collecting delivery information is not required, as I will collect that on my side, they just need to take the payment then tell me the outcome so then my system can perform the correct action?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this tutorial and sample application
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal